# How to search tweets in real time using a recursive fashion?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I have used to search a tweets using search method with passing a keyword in twitter4j. This is my code

```
String query = "Cricket";
Query searchQuery = new Query(query);

try {
    QueryResult queryResult = twitter.search(searchQuery);
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    log.error("Unable to search query = {}", query, e);
}
```

When i test this code, its showing only top 20 tweets. But i need to search a tweets in recursive fashion. So, how can i search a tweets in real time using a recursive fashion?

Comment: Did you take a closer look to the java doc of the query class? I think this is pretty self explaining: http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Can you point me to the appropriate method to perform this search, I am already using the query interface:
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html               What should I do in addition, to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException { 

   Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
   Query query = new Query("**your query**");
   query.setRpp(100); // here you show 100 tweets
   QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
   for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
      System.out.println(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
   }
 }
```

Why do you want to use recursive function?